# Как автоматически добавить variables при установке airflow?

Tags: docker, airflow

Стоит задача при установке airflow через docker автоматически добавить variables и connections. Я задумал эту задачу выполнить при установке airflow через выполнение команд
airflow variables import.

1. Для этого, я создал файлы: variables.json и connections.json в которые записал информацию о переменных и соединениях.
2. Создал файл Dockerfile

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.6.3-python3.10

USER root

COPY requirements.txt /opt/airflow/requirements.txt
COPY connections.json /opt/airflow
COPY variables.json /opt/airflow
COPY set_variables.sh /opt/airflow

COPY geckodriver/ /usr/local/bin

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y firefox-esr
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y chromium

USER airflow

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --user -r /opt/airflow/requirements.txt
RUN airflow connections import /opt/airflow/connections.json
RUN airflow variables import /opt/airflow/variables.json
```

4. Изменил файл docker-compose?, добавил туда инструкцию build

```
    version: '3.8'
    x-airflow-common:
      &airflow-common
      #image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.6.3}
      build:
        context: ./init
      environment:
        &airflow-common-env
```

4. Собственно вопрос. Последние две команды airflow connections import не работают, поскольку при развертывании airflow airflow-worker еще не запущен. Что нужно изменить?
5. Может быть кто-то знает как выполнить команду в контейнере airflow-worker, после его создания?